# Why can't I ping my database from JDBC Connection Pool?

Tags: mysql, glassfish, database-connection, connection-pooling, glassfish-4

I've been following [this](http://mariosgaee.blogspot.rs/2009/12/mysql-connection-pool-in-glassfish.html) link to set up a MySql connection pool for glassfish server (located on a Debian server machine).

When trying to ping the database (located on a CentOS server machine), I get the following error from glassfish server:

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for MySqlTrace. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.
```

I should stress that I am accessing the DB remotely (from my Windows laptop) with a workbench client with no problem what so ever and with the same credentials (I quadruple checked!).

**I'm also posting the domain1/logs/server.log**

```
[2015-12-09T09:39:58.825+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [jdbc.exc_cnfe_ds] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.util] [tid: _ThreadID=101 _ThreadName=admin-listener(12)] [timeMillis: 1449653998825] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RAR5099 : Wrong class name or classpath for Datasource Object
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:285)
        at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1300)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:696)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:425)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.connectors.admin.cli.PingConnectionPool.execute(PingConnectionPool.java:143)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateExecCommand.executeCommandLegacyFormat(TemplateExecCommand.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateCommandGetResource.processGetLegacyFormat(TemplateCommandGetResource.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:125)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:91)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:198)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:946)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:181)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]


[2015-12-09T09:39:58.829+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [test.connection.pool.failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=101 _ThreadName=admin-listener(12)] [timeMillis: 14$
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ MySqlTrace ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource]]

[2015-12-09T09:39:58.832+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=102 _ThreadName=admin-listener(13)] [timeMillis: 1449653998832] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'https://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=MySqlTrace}']]
```

**So what am I doing wrong here?**

**EDIT1:**

```
root@trace glassfish/lib# ls
appclient       endorsed                     nadmin
appserv-rt.jar  gf-client.jar                nadmin.bat
asadmin         install                      package-appclient.xml
client          javaee.jar                   registration
deployment      jndi-properties.jar          schemas
dtds            monitor
embedded        mysql-connector-java-5.1.38
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your glassfish server is missing the MySQL jdbc driver. Download mysql_xxx.jar to glashfish_home/lib.

See https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

This blog seems to give a step by step including the jdbc driver https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot, i only had the folder inside as you can see in the edit. I forgot to pull out the .jar file from it...